# How to get url from browser in php?

Tags: php

I want to get url in php.

I want to access the **"index.php"** file in the **"book folder"** under the **"demoproject"** like this:

```
demoproject/book/index.php
```

What I want:

I want to access the index.php file when someone type in the browser

```
demoproject/book/page2
```

Here in the index.php file I have written the code to access the page2 dynamically.
If user type page3 the page3 content will load on index.php file

Here is what I am doing:

```
// Assume user type in the browser
// demoproject/book/page2

$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$errors = array();
//get request url
$request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//print_r($request_uri);
echo $request_uri[3];   // page2

?>
```

But my problem is that I am able to access the below url with index.php

```
demoproject/book/index.php
```

But not able to get page2 when user type on browser like below:

```
demoproject/book/page2
```

I only want when user type:

```
demoproject/book/page2     // I want to get page2 on index.php
demoproject/book/page3     // I want to get page3 on index.php
demoproject/book/page4     // I want to get page4 on index.php
demoproject/book/page5     // I want to get page5 on index.php
demoproject/book/page6     // I want to get page6 on index.php
```

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Your webserver needs to know how to handle those requests. (Research ModRewrite for Apache for example)

Comment: You originally tagged the question with cakephp. If that's what you're using the documentation should have instructions on how to configure your web server correctly (cakephp comes with a router).

Answer (score -1):

What I would suggest is you maintain the following file structure :

```
demoproject/bookName/page1.php
demoproject/bookName/page2.php
demoproject/bookName/page3.php etc
```

However I understand you want to remove the dot.php extension from the file name while accessing the page for which you can use a .htaccess file to redirect any requests to the respective page. For example :

If your users go to -

```
url : demoproject/bookName/page2
```

They will be automatically redirected to -

```
url : demoproject/bookName/page2.php
```

While the url will NOT show the dot.php extension.

Use the following .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: What if OP is using nginx as webserver?

Comment: So let her clarify that instead of assuming. The response I have given is based on what mostly beginners use and their environment setup.